# Conditional Window Functions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sales table that looks like this:

```
store_id    cust_id   txn_id   txn_date   amt       industry
200         1         1        20180101   21.01     1000   
200         2         2        20200102   20.01     1000
200         2         3        20200103   19        1000
200         3         4        20180103   19        1000
200         4         5        20200103   21.01     1000
300         2         6        20200104   1.39      2000
300         1         7        20200105   12.24     2000
300         1         8        20200105   25.02     2000
400         2         9        20180106   103.1     1000
400         2         10       20200107   21.3      1000
```

Here's the code to generate this sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE sales(
    store_id INT,
    cust_id INT,
    txn_id INT,
    txn_date bigint,
    amt float,
    industry INT);

INSERT INTO sales VALUES(200,1,1,20180101,21.01,1000);
INSERT INTO sales VALUES(200,2,2,20200102,20.01,1000);
INSERT INTO sales VALUES(200,2,3,20200103,19.00,1000);
INSERT INTO sales VALUES(200,3,4,20180103,19.00,1000);
INSERT INTO sales VALUES(200,4,5,20200103,21.01,1000);
INSERT INTO sales VALUES(300,2,6,20200104,1.39,2000);
INSERT INTO sales VALUES(300,1,7,20200105,12.24,2000);
INSERT INTO sales VALUES(300,1,8,20200105,25.02,2000);
INSERT INTO sales VALUES(400,2,9,20180106,103.1,1000);
INSERT INTO sales VALUES(400,2,10,20200107,21.3,1000);
```

What I would like to do is create a new table, `results` that answers the question: what percentage of my VIP customers have, since January 3rd 2020, shopped i) at my store only; ii) at my store and at other stores in the same industry; iii) at only other stores in the same industry? Define a VIP customer to be someone who has shopped at a given store at least once since 2019.

Here's the target output table:

```
store    industry   pct_my_store_only   pct_both   pct_other_stores_only
200      1000         0.5               0.5         0.0
300      2000         0.5               0.5         0.0
400      1000         0.0               1.0         0.0
```

I'm trying to use window functions to accomplish this. Here's what I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE results as
    SELECT s.store_id, s.industry,
    COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN s.txn_date>=20200103 THEN s.cust_id END)) * 1.0 / sum(count(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN s.txn_date>=20200103 THEN s.cust_id END))) OVER (PARTITION BY s.industry) AS pct_my_store_only
    ...AS pct_both
    ...AS pct_other_stores_only
    FROM sales s
    WHERE sales.txn_date>=20190101 
    GROUP BY s.store_id, s.industry;
```

The above does not seem to be correct; how can I correct this?

Comment: Pease show us the desired results for your sample data (your have 3 empty columns)

Comment: @GMB: thanks, I've completed the target table and added a new customer (customer 4) who only shopped with store 200.

Comment: @Caerus when you say, your store ? which one you mean ?

Comment: @JagaSrik: I mean that each store has a set of VIP customers who have shopped with that store since 2019. Of those customers, who have shopped with only that store? For example, store 200 has 2 VIP customers (customers 2, 4). Of those, only customer 4 has shopped only with store 200 since January 3, 2020. The other has shopped with other stores in the same industry (industry 1000) as well.

Comment: What is the definition of a VIP customer?

Comment: @forpas: a customer who has shopped with a specific store at least once since 2019.

Comment: @Caerus can you please explain how did you get this values in the columns - pct_my_store_only   pct_both   pct_other_stores_only , for example 200 store  you have 0.5 0.5 and 0 ..for the data presented

Comment: @JagaSrik: Store 200 has 2 VIP customers (2,4). Of these, only customer 4 shopped exclusively at store 200 since 20200103. Customer 2 also shopped  at store 400. So, 50% of store 200's VIP customers shopped only at store 200, while 50% shopped at both store 200 and other stores in the same industry.

Comment: The customer with id = 1 shopped only from store_id = 300.  Why is pct_my_store_only  = 0.0?

Comment: @forpas: You're correct--typo on my side. I've updated the post, thank you.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff do you have some advice here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the distinct store_ids and industries to the concatenated distinct store_ids and industries for each customer and then use window function `avg()` with the function `find_in_set()` to determine if a customer how many customer have shopped or not from each store:

```
with 
  stores as (
    select distinct store_id, industry
    from sales
    where txn_date >= 20190103
  ),
  customers as (
    select cust_id, 
           group_concat(distinct store_id) stores,
           group_concat(distinct industry) industries 
    from sales
    where txn_date >= 20190103
    group by cust_id
 ),
  cte as (
  select *,
    avg(concat(s.store_id) = concat(c.stores)) over (partition by s.store_id, s.industry) pct_my_store_only,
    avg(find_in_set(s.store_id, c.stores) = 0) over (partition by s.industry) pct_other_stores_only
    from stores s inner join customers c 
    on find_in_set(s.industry, c.industries) and find_in_set(s.store_id, c.stores)
  )  
select distinct store_id, industry, 
       pct_my_store_only,
       1 - pct_my_store_only - pct_other_stores_only pct_both,   
       pct_other_stores_only
from cte       
order by store_id, industry
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bb0902825796a5176fd14db6717ae8ab).
Results:

```
> store_id | industry | pct_my_store_only | pct_both | pct_other_stores_only
> -------: | -------: | ----------------: | -------: | --------------------:
>      200 |     1000 |            0.5000 |   0.5000 |                0.0000
>      300 |     2000 |            0.5000 |   0.5000 |                0.0000
>      400 |     1000 |            0.0000 |   1.0000 |                0.0000
```

Comment: thank you this looks great. Does this account for the restriction that we're looking for the percent of VIPs who have shopped since 20200103?

Comment: In your code there is `txn_date>=20190101` and I copied that. I edited now for `txn_date>=20190103`

Comment: Right, sorry, this is a complex problem and I'm probably unclear in my wording. A VIP is someone who has shopped at my store at least once since 20190101. For each store, we're looking for the percent of VIPs who have shopped i) my store only, ii) my store and other stores in the same industry as me; iii)  only other stores since 20200103. This is extremely close--I think we only need one additional date filter, perhaps in the cte?

Comment: The filter txn_date >= 20190103 exists in the first 2 CTEs.

Comment: Right, the January 2019 filter in the first two CTEs is to get the VIPs. If we're looking for the purchases since January 2020, presumably we'll need another filter, no?

Comment: The query needs the VIPs who did the purchases since January 2020 because the number of VIPs will be averaged. This is what the 2nd CTE does. The 1st CTE returns the distinct stores where the VIPs made the purchases since January 2020.

Comment: This is Nice one